# KCL2 -Multi stream consumer - Configured streams can be in same account and cross account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kcl, amazon-kinesis-kpl

In my project there is a requirement of a KCL2 multi stream consumer which is consuming from streams which are both in same AWS account and cross account.

Is there any way to achieve this configuration using java as I can see that we cannot have multiple config builder for kinesis client with different credential provider as for cross account we need to have StsAssumeRoleCredentialsProvider and for same account we can have default credential provider?

Please suggest

I did not find any relevant documentation for this configuration